# Does anybody care that the stats API isn't working for all pages?

Tags: api, statistics

See my question here:
[API stat return shows 0 Likes, but page displays a non-zero number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22619225/api-stat-return-shows-0-likes-but-page-displays-a-non-zero-number)

Comment: possible duplicate of [API stat return shows 0 Likes, but page displays a non-zero number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22619225/api-stat-return-shows-0-likes-but-page-displays-a-non-zero-number)